# Hotkeys Swapped Cannot Restore

Tags: shortcut

Suddenly at the node editor left click and the Ctrl+left click (cutting nodes link with little knife shaped cursor) operations swapped. I really do not know how that was happened.
Anyway, I disabled the node wrangler, but nothing is changed.
I tried to change hotkeys as in the image of the UI, again nothing is changed.
All my other little approaches aren't effective so far. (restarting software, computer and so on...) Thanks in advance.

[image: here is the node hotkeys that I thought is relevant]

Answer (score 1):

Normally this should work: press these little 3 bars in the lower left corner of your preferences and you get:

[image]

Then choose "load factory preferences".

Comment: Yep, that is a useful solution but, that didn't worked either.

Comment: I found the issue. Animation node cut link tool activated itself, and the toolbar were out of the view. But somehow it is effecting the shader nodes too. And still remain active after disable the add-on. Bugs to report.